# Can't reinstall Ubuntu from LiveCD (16.04) after deleting it

Tags: boot, live-cd

I had to delete my Ubuntu partition and now trying to reinstall it with the LiveCD (version 16.04). But I get stuck at:

```
drm:i915_gem_init_stolen [i915]] *ERROR* conflict detected with stolen region: [0xbba00000 - 0xbfa00000]
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: failed to load fecs_inst
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000 10005080 00002004
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000 10005080 00002004
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000 10005080 00002004
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000 10005080 00002004
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000 10005080 00002004
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000 10005080 00002004
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000 10005080 00002004
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000 10005080 00002004
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000 10005080 00002004
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000 10005080 00002004
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000 10005080 00002004
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000 10005080 00002004
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000 10005080 00002004
```

I allready tried different Ubuntu versions. I used the same LiveCD successfully before.

Comment: @anx, I added the version and tried to install Ubuntu with "nomodeset". I  was able to install Ubuntu but now I can't boot into it. When I again try to boot from the LiveCD I end up at the same point above.

Comment: Okay, I did it. I went into the partition management. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with <kbd>f1</kbd> during the boot and reinstalled Ubuntu while rebuilding the partition table.