# Conflict detected with stolen region?

Tags: 16.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my machine. When I insert a DVD I burned with Ubuntu 16.04 on it I first see the "keyboard=person" symbol. I've tried hitting the down arrow key and a bunch of others, but nothing responds. After a few seconds of the "keyboard=person" a bunch of text pops up. The first line is

```
[   5.297955] [drm:i915_gem_init_stolen [1915]] ERROR conflict detect with stolen region: [0xbba00000 - 0xbfa00000]
```

The next 4 items are EDID checksum's being invalid. After that it says

```
DDC responded, but no EID for HDMI-A-3
```

There are some other lines, then the final line is

```
gr: init failed -110
```

I have no idea what to do with this information. I've found some references to stolen region from a bug fixed in 2014, but I couldn't find anything that would fix the error. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Up until the text pops up, your description of the boot is perfectly normal.

Comment: Try pressing **F1** during boot. It apparently worked for [this person with the same issue](http://askubuntu.com/q/783039/301745).